# compare first word for each line in csv file and print the line which match and on failure also print lines not matching first word

Tags: shell

I have a csv file, sample below. It just has 4 lines but in actual no of rows is not fixed. It can be 7 or 10 or 100 or many more. I want to separate the file in two other csv files. One csv should have all the lines whose first word matches and another file should have all the lines whose first word does not  matches. I want to have the shell script for this problem.
Sample csv file is like below:

```
DBA1,IDA1,RefA11,RefA12,RefA13,RefA14,RefA15
DBA1,IDA1,RefA21,RefA22,RefA23,RefA24,RefA25,RefA26
DBB1,IDB1,RefBB11,RefBB12,RefBB13,RefBB14,RefBB15,RefBB16,RefBB17,RefBB18
DBB2,IDB2,RefB1,RefB2,RefB3,RefB4,RefB5,RefB6,RefB7,RefB8
```

I was not able to get the script working.

I am expecting the two output file as explained here.
One csv should be like below as first word is matching in these two lines

```
DBA1,IDA1,RefA11,RefA12,RefA13,RefA14,RefA15
DBA1,IDA1,RefA21,RefA22,RefA23,RefA24,RefA25,RefA26
```

Another csv should be

```
DBB1,IDB1,RefBB11,RefBB12,RefBB13,RefBB14,RefBB15,RefBB16,RefBB17,RefBB18
DBB2,IDB2,RefB1,RefB2,RefB3,RefB4,RefB5,RefB6,RefB7,RefB8
```

Comment: _all the lines whose first word matches_ Are you looking for the program to decide this or to give it as a parameter?

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for your query. Yes I need a shell program to decide and create two separate csv as explained in my problem statement. pls let me know if still more info is required to help me

Comment: What determines a 'match' or not? Where's the value the rows are supposed to be tested for come from?

Comment: Hi Shawn..Thanks for your query. rows are part of a csv which will be user input and number of rows can be anything from 1 to 200. first word of each row where comma is separator shall be use for match for next row first word.. I hope I answered your query. if still more details needed, pls let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not quite clear to me, but from what I read:

> One csv should have all the lines whose first word matches

```
$ WORD=DBA1
$ grep "^$WORD," file.csv
DBA1,IDA1,RefA11,RefA12,RefA13,RefA14,RefA15
DBA1,IDA1,RefA21,RefA22,RefA23,RefA24,RefA25,RefA26
```

> and another file should have all the lines whose first word does not match

```
$ grep -v "^$WORD," file.csv
DBB1,IDB1,RefBB11,RefBB12,RefBB13,RefBB14,RefBB15,RefBB16,RefBB17,RefBB18
DBB2,IDB2,RefB1,RefB2,RefB3,RefB4,RefB5,RefB6,RefB7,RefB8
```

Grep's `-v` option reverses the logic to print all lines that don't match. If you want to ask the user for WORD, just use `read WORD`.

Comment: Thanks Jens but it needs to be more robust for my problem. the word is not a fixed string. it should be captured at run time so we have to first get the word and then use further

Comment: @NitinKumar I have adapted the answer to assign to WORD and use $WORD.

Comment: Thanks @Jens It helped to formalize my approach .

Comment: @NitinKumar Great. The next step is to upvote (clicking the up arrow) and possibly accept the answer that helped you most by clicking the check mark.